# EJB 3.1 Transaction propagation

Tags: transactions, db2, ejb, locks, propagation

I have 3 EJB stateless beans.
A - on business layer.
B, C - of persistence layer.

Bean A calls B and C to update some data in database (DB2).

But unfortunatly, on calling bean C, database locks.
Is it possible that B and C executes in defferent transactions? Otherwise I can't understand why DB2 locks...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate as your persistence provider, then it provides a transaction annotation called `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` on the business method. This annotation runs the method in a separate transaction. So I think there should be an alternative for this in JPA. But not sure.

Comment: So, If I not put this annotation on business method, then no transaction will be started. Separate transactions will be for B and C?

Comment: If you dont put this annotation then the method will run in the parent transaction, that is the transaction will complete if the parent method which invoked this method completes. And I am assuming that you are invoking methods in B & C from A so till A completes B and C will run in same transaction

Comment: Also can you please post your code, if it is not confidential ??

Answer (score 0):

I have JBoss AS 7.
I have two entities Employer and EMployee. Employee has link to employer.

I have

```
@Stateless
EployerService {
 ....
 public void lockEmployer (long id) {
    Employer employer = employerDAO.findById(id);
    employer.setLocked(true);
    employerDAO.updateEmployer(employer);
    employeeDAO.updateEmployeesByEmployerId(id);
 }  
}
```

in EmployeeDAO

```
updateEmployeesByEmployerId (long empId) {
   em.createQuery("update Employee set locked = true where emplopyerId=:id").setParameter("id", empId).executeUpdate();

}
```

in EmployerDAO

```
udpateEmplopyer(Employer employer) {
  em.merge(employer);
}
```

When I put all logic from both dao in one DAO - no locks!